# How to view an application certificate on Mac OS.?

Tags: macos, operating-system

How to view the certificate for a particular app installed in our Mac OS.?
for example: /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app I want to view the certificate for this app.

I do not want to list all the certificates in KeyChain Access and search for the terminal app.
Is there any command line of UI way to view the certificate of an installed app.?

Thanks

NK

Answer (score 15):

Here's You can check how app is signed and see Cert Authority:

`codesign -d -vvv /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app`

Comment: Thanks Mateusz.
I have a installer app to be installed on a Mac OS, I do not have a Apple Developer Certificate and I could code sign the installer.
will it work launching this app without Gatekeeper blocking it.?

Comment: @user3457694 Sorry I'm not sure I understand what You mean. You have certificate only for Installers? Please provide more info so I could help You.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion.
I have an installer app with .pfx certificate which is signed by verisign. I am trying to use the same .pfx certificate for mac osx-10.9 by importing and adding to keychains. but My App installer bundle for Mac OSX has osx-intel unix executable build with xcode has issues while codesigning. error as shown below,
myapp.app: bundle format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
In subcomponent: myapp.app/Contents/MacOS/osx-intel

Note: If try to code sign individually for the osx-intel unix executable I am still getting errors.